# Difference between Carnap and Quine's views

Tags: epistemology, ontology, philosophy-of-language, realism, quine

Could someone explain to me, in easy language, what the main differences are between *Carnap* and *Quine*'s views regarding internal / external questions and realism? Quine called Carnap a Platoist, yet I don't understand why and what exactly the differences are.

Could someone elaborate, please?

Comment: See [Quine's objections to Carnap](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quine/#AnaSynDisArgAgaLogEmp).

Comment: I find that highly complex material. I need someone to explain it to me in a clear and concise way, but thanks, Mauro.

Comment: Why do you think that a very complex issue like de debate Carnap-Quine about analytic sentences vs synthetic sentences, *holism* and *a priori* can be explained "in easy language" ?

Comment: Because I think that everything can be explained in easy language :) Especially using examples makes it easy too.

Comment: According to Carnap, *analytic truths* are true as a result of their *meaning*.

Comment: According to Quine, the nature of *meaning* is obscure.

Comment: According to Quine meanings are **not** some kind of “objects”: they must not be confused with objects because they must not be confused with references (objects of the world).

Comment: Quine’s final proposal to define analyticity without an appeal to meaning.

Comment: In the end, Quine rejects the notion of “analyticity” as imbued with metaphysics.